# Organizing MVC Backend

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, backend

How should I properly organize controllers if I have to create different methods for internal API and external (public) API.

Variants:

- Not to divide controllers: [Model]Controller will have methods for both APIs;
- Make one Controller for all external requests: PublicApiController
- Divide each controller by its purpose: [Model]Controller, [Model]PublicController
- Divide by something else like PublicReadController, PublicWriteController, etc.

The reasons I ask it are aesthetics and code scalability and readability in prospect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can create as many folders in `Controllers` as you like, what I actually doing in my project is:

```
/Http/Controllers
| - V1
    | - Internal
        | - UsersController
        | - ProductsController
        | - UploadsController
        | - BackupController
    | - External
        | - Auth
            | - PasswordController
            | - ResetController
        | - DashboardController
        | - UsersController
        | - ProductsController
```

** The V1 is optional. I like it so that in the future I could change to V2 and replace some controllers if I need to*

By doing so, you can have your route group load up different namespace/middleware to provide correct auth to each group of controllers. Each controller will then focus on just a few things to do, nice and neat, and scalable.

Then I would place my business logic, in a folder `app/Services` and write all my business logic in there, hence this result in thin controllers and thin models. Controller is nothing but a place to use services, route requests, and responses.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I like to follow a pattern whereby a controller doesn't have any custom methods. 
Thus you end up with lots of very thin controllers, so I would break up the controllers to only handle generic RESTful resource methods like `index` `update` `store` `destroy` `show`.
I would not focus on coupling your model layer with your controller layer.

for example:
If we have a endpoint that updates a user's profile image
instead of having this structure `UserController@updateImage` we would have `/User/ImageController@update` thus always stick to generic methods.

Comment: Thank you! Ideal decision :)